# php mysql and form error

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have a form error when i put password and click submit button query executed but on database password row empty :(

please help me to sort out this problem i tried but didn't solve. php contain html via double quotes
thanks

```
<?php echo errormessage();


      if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']) AND isset($_REQUEST['token']) && !empty($_REQUEST['token'])){
        // Verify data
        $email = mysql_prep($_REQUEST['email']); // Set email variable
        $token = mysql_prep($_REQUEST['token']); // Set hash variable

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT email, hash FROM job_seeker WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$token."'"); 
        $num_rows  = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($num_rows > 0){



        echo '<form method="post" action=""><table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" >
        <tr>
          <td width="40%">New Password :</td>
          <td width="60%"><input type="password" required="" value="" name="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm New Password  : </td>
          <td><input type="password" required="" value="" name="cpass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>

      </table></form>';



//<?php          //var_dump($_POST);

          @$pass = mysql_prep($_POST['pass']);
          @$cpass = mysql_prep($_POST['cpass']);

         if(isset($_POST)){

           if($pass == $cpass)
          {
          //echo $hashed_password = password_encrypt($pass); 
            $hashed_password = $pass; 
          $result = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE job_seeker SET hashed_password='$hashed_password', hash='' WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$token."'");
          if ($result) {
        // Success
          $_SESSION["message"] = "Password Successfully Changed.";

          } else {
            // Failure
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Oops... Something went wrong.";
          }
         }
          }
        }else{
           $_SESSION["message"] = "OOPS: Link Expired. Please check your inbox.";
        }
      }else{
        //var_dump($_REQUEST);
       redirect_to('index.php');
       }
      ?>
```

Comment: Besides the fact that your code does not do what you want it to do, it's terribly insecure. keep in mind that you still need to fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities after this

Comment: error: when click on submit button query executed and password row remain empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved if(isset($_POST)){ lol every one gave new instruction except to change the code if(isset($_POST))

Answer (score 1):

The code line:

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']) AND isset($_REQUEST['token']) && !empty($_REQUEST['token'])){
```

checks for the password and executes query only if the password (token) is posted.
Please update it to:

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email'])){
```

And you code will work.

Comment: Solved it was db problem i set var char to 255 and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the "password change" portion of your code.

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE job_seeker SET hashed_password='$hashed_password', hash='' WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$token."'");
```

depending on your php configuration, it might set the password column to

> "$hashed_password"

or to whatever was in the variable `$hashed_password`

You probably meant to do this :

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE job_seeker SET hashed_password='".$hashed_password."', hash='' WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$token."'");
```

But that is still a terrible idea, because this is vulnerable to sql injection.

Also, make sure you have your column names right, down to the letter. ( i can't check that for you )

Comment: accutally when i set $hashed_password = "something"; its working fine but via form not working i insert form through echo

Answer (score 0):

I could be because you have predefined Value in form.

Try to change this:

```
 echo '<form method="post" action=""><table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" >
    <tr>
      <td width="40%">New Password :</td>
      <td width="60%"><input type="password" required="" value="" name="pass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm New Password  : </td>
      <td><input type="password" required="" value="" name="cpass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>

  </table></form>';
```

For this:

```
echo '<form method="post" action=""><table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" >
    <tr>
      <td width="40%">New Password :</td>
      <td width="60%"><input type="password" required="" name="pass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm New Password  : </td>
      <td><input type="password" required="" name="cpass"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>

  </table></form>';
```

Without value attribute

Comment: If you would like to check this theory try to put inside Value something. For example make value="xyz" Then try to execute form i can bet that you will receive "xyz" in database :)

Comment: Problem solved  `if(isset($_POST)){ ` lol every one gave new instruction except to change the code `if(isset($_POST)){ `